# Code not producing the correct value - formula in loop to find minimum based on increments from 0 to 360

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I have searched threads to see if there is anything specific to this issue however, I haven't found anything that quite matches what I need.  I have a formula, in fact several formulae, which vary with angular position around a circumference.  I have so far been using excel and have created the angular range in increments of 1 degrees and simply used formulae for each cell to calculate values.  However, the file has got pretty large and also since many of the formulae vary with angle it would be useful to learn how to do this.

In all cases I am looping from 0 degrees to 360 degrees and want to find either the max or min.  The code I have used thus far is as follows (apologies at this stage for my horrendously clunky and poor programming - I am very new to this):-

```
Function C_1c_Long(Radius, rm)

Dim phi As Double
Dim C_1c As Integer
Dim Angle As Integer
Dim pi As Double
Dim C_1cphi As Integer

Angle = 0
pi = Application.WorksheetFunction.pi

Do

C_1cphi = (2 * Radius + rm * Sin(phi)) / (2 * (Radius + rm * Sin(phi)))
Angle = Angle + 1
phi = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(Angle)

Loop Until C_1c < C_1cphi

C_1c = C_1cphi

C_1c_Long = C_1c

End Function
```

Thanks in advance - I know this is probably very simple but so am I I'm afraid when it comes to speaking VBA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the technical issues that should help you with any VBA program that you write:

1)  You haven't set `C_1c` equal to anything before  you test against it as your loop conditional.  VBA automatically sets it equal to `0`, which may or may not be what you want it to do.  It is always a good idea to initialize your variables so that whoever is reading your code (like you 6 months from now) will know what you were thinking.

2)  You've declared `C_1c` and `C_1cphi` as `Integer`s, but then you try to store floating point numbers into them.  This will probably cause you to lose precision that you want.

3)  you haven't provided a type for `Radius` or `rm`.  In this case it is clear that you want numbers.  And, there is no necessity that they be integers, so I would declare both as `Double`.  In addition you know that you will be returning a number (right know, an `Integer`, but based on (2) it should also be a double), so I would declare that as well.  This becomes

```
Function C_1c_Long(Radius as Double, rm as Double) as Double
```

If in the future you want to have a function where you don't know the variable type when you write the code, just declare it as a `Variant`.  This is once again, so that you are being clear to whoever reads your code later what you were thinking.

**Now to answer the question of how to solve your problem of maximizing the function.**

The short answer is throw out your code.  Because this is a continuous problem (how do you know the max isn't at 65.45502269421 degrees?) searching just the integers is not a good idea.  So here are 2 alternative solutions to the problem

1)  If you know calculus, then this is straight forward, and you can calculate it by hand, and code up a solution appropriately (I am assuming, without writing error checking code, that `Radius > rm`):

```
Function C_1c_Long(Radius As Double, rm As Double) As Double
    C_1c_Long = (2 * Radius - rm) / (2 * Radius - 2 * rm)
End Function
```

2)  If you don't know calculus, then you can apply the solver that is included with Excel to perform this by placing the formula in one cell, the angle in another, and telling the solver to maximize the formula by changing the angle.

3)  For completeness sake, here is how to tweak your algorithm to find the maximum value just for integer degrees.  Declare a variable to hold the max.  Then, loop through *all* of the integers and compare the value against the current max.  And, in this case we can either initialize the maximum as being the first computed value or some number that outrageously out of the range of possible values.

```
Function C_1c_Long(Radius As Double, rm As Double) As Double

Dim phi As Double
Dim Angle As Double
Dim C_1cphi As Double
Dim max As Double

phi = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(0#)
max = (2 * Radius + rm * Sin(phi)) / (2 * (Radius + rm * Sin(phi)))

For Angle = 1 To 360
    phi = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(0#)
    C_1cphi = (2 * Radius + rm * Sin(phi)) / (2 * (Radius + rm * Sin(phi)))
    If C_1cphi > max Then
        max = C_1cphi
    End If
Next Angle

C_1c_Long = C_1cphi

End Function
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks - having this structure should mean I am able to play tunes on this for calculating various other parameters with more complicated formulae.